# Firebase refuses Instagram API token

Tags: swift, firebase, instagram-api

I want to authenticate a user in Firebase with an `Instagram API` custom token. I got my token from the `Instagram API`, but when I send my token to the Firebase signIn with the custom token method, Firebase refuses my token. Here is the error I'm getting:

> FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid assertion format., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN.
>   this is my token format:
>   12634564280.0cbnf82.ee84rtyu1574c349a3433b9f0ce0789

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An Instagram API token is not a valid Firebase Authentication token. You'll need to [create a custom Firebase Authentication token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to be able to sign into Firebase.

Comment: thank you frank for you quick reply ! my problem is solved I think now I just have to pass the instagram clientID in the createCustomToken firebase method to generate my token and auth my user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Instagram API token is not a valid Firebase Authentication token. You'll need to [create a custom Firebase Authentication token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to be able to sign into Firebase.

Comment: Hi, I need to create a instagram login using firebase too. Do you any example on how to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth?